# Run multiline for loop in a single line

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiline

```
>>> query='';for var in xrange(9):\n\tquery+=str(var)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    query='';for var in xrange(9):\n\tquery+=str(var)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


>>> query='';for var in xrange(9): query+=str(var)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    query='';for var in xrange(9): query+=str(var)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why wont the above code work? But the following works

```
>>> query=""
>>> for var in xrange(9): query+=str(var)
... 
>>> query
'012345678'
>>>
```

Comment: why are you trying to put the for on the same line as query=''? This is not C. Python does not use semicolons and you are supposed to use white space to separate commands, not cram them all onto one line.

Comment: @JosephGagliardo: actual things is something else. This was just an example

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The code you supplied does not compile because it is not valid Python syntax. Do not try to put the query = '' on the same line, put it on it's own line and it works fine.

Comment: This is far from "good" Pythonic code, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm getting this code from outside the file and have to use this in exec()

Comment: Next question: why are you `exec`ing code from an external file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `;` is only allowed to combine "small statements". Those are expressions, print, and the like. A `for` loop, on the other hand, is a compound statement. See the [Full Grammar Specification](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html):

```
simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
small_stmt: (expr_stmt | print_stmt  | del_stmt | pass_stmt | flow_stmt |
             import_stmt | global_stmt | exec_stmt | assert_stmt)
...
compound_stmt: if_stmt | while_stmt | for_stmt | try_stmt | with_stmt | funcdef | classdef | decorated
```

In your example, if this is more than just to illustrate your question, you could rewrite it as

```
query = ''.join(str(var) for var in xrange(9))
```

Or if you really *really* need to `exec` that multiline statement, you can add a `\n` between the assignment and the `for` loop (as you already did in another place):

```
>>> exec("query=''\nfor var in xrange(9):\n\tquery+=str(var)\nprint query")
012345678
```

But note that this does only work in `exec`, not in the interactive shell directly:

```
>>> query=''\nfor var in xrange(9):\n\tquery+=str(var)\nprint query
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you wanted a generator expression:

```
>>> query  = "".join(str(var) for var in xrange(9))
>>> query
'012345678'
```

Answer (score 2):

***A for statement is a compound statement which by definition cannot follow a semicolon***

Quoting the python documentation

[Compound statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html)

> Compound statements consist of one or more ‘clauses.’ A clause consists of a header and a ‘suite.’ The clause headers of a particular compound statement are all at the same indentation level. Each clause header begins with a uniquely identifying keyword and ends with a colon. A suite is a group of statements controlled by a clause. **A suite can be one or more semicolon-separated simple statements on the same line as the header, following the header’s colon, or it can be one or more indented statements on subsequent lines. Only the latter form of suite can contain nested compound statements**; the following is  illegal, mostly because it wouldn’t be clear to which if clause a following else clause would belong:

and it so happens that a for statement is a compound statement in Python

```
compound_stmt ::=  if_stmt
                    | while_stmt
                    | for_stmt
                    | try_stmt
                    | with_stmt
                    | funcdef
                    | classdef
                    | decorated
```

and so it cannot follow a semicolon

Comment: so what is the workaround for this? How can I make this for loop work?

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of Python programmers only use line breaks to separate statements, and I suspect most don't even know the semicolon is a possibility.

And (as Abhijit said) that feature is limited: it only works for simple statements like variable assignments and function calls, not for control statements like "if", "for", "while", etc.